# Number of Connected Components in Complex Plane of Complement of Domain ( Open, Connected set)

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I saw similar questions but not quite this: I am trying to show that the number of components of the complement a domain  D ( A Domain is an open connected set) , i.e., $\mathbb C -D $ in the Complex plane ( Equiv., the plane) is countable. My argument is that , by density of $\mathbb Q$ on the Reals  ( And hence of $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q $ in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$) , each component would have an element $(q_1, q_2)$ of $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q $ and therefore there can be only countably-many components. But then I considered the case of a punctured disk $D(a,r) -\{pt\} $: One of the connected components of its complement is the singleton $\{pt\}$ which does not (necessarily) include a point in $ \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q $. So the result holds for non-punctured domains. How can I generalize for all domains?

Comment: What you are trying to prove is false. Take as $D$ the whole of $\Bbb C$ without a Cantor set on the real axis

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: But a domain is connected. Is D-C connected? Can the result be changed/restricted so that it is true?

Comment: Yes, it is connected (path connected in fact). I don't see a simple way to make the statement true

Comment: The complement of the Cantor set considered as a subspace of $\mathbb C$, is a domain, but the Cantor set is totally disconnected and uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

Take any closed subset $A \subset \mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$ with uncountably many components, e.g. the Cantor set. Then $D =  \mathbb C \setminus A$ is a domain whose complement has uncountably many components.